# How to Query DynamoDb for multiValueQueryParameters using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

Title: Trouble Querying DynamoDB with multiValueQueryParameters in Node.js

Description:

Hi, I'm working on a project where I need to query DynamoDB for multiValueQueryParameters using Node.js. I'm following the guidelines provided in the official AWS blog post. According to the documentation, AWS API Gateway processes URLs like this:

```
https://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/pets/search?petType=dog&petType=fish
```

and interprets it as:

```
        {
          "resource": "/pets/search",
          "path": "/pets/search",
          "httpMethod": "GET",
          "headers": {
            // ...
          },
          "queryStringParameters": { "petType": "fish" },
          "multiValueQueryStringParameters": { "petType": [ "dog", "fish" ] },
          // ...
        }
```

Now, I'm trying to query the petType in DynamoDB, and I've constructed the following queryParam in Node.js which is returning empty response.

```
        const queryParams = {
            TableName: tableName,
            IndexName: 'location-index',
            KeyConditionExpression: '#petName = :petName',
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                '#petName': 'PetName'
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':petName': petName
            },
            FilterExpression: 'PetType IN (:petTypes)',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':petTypes': petTypes
            }
        };

        dynamodb.query(queryParams, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error querying DynamoDB:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Query results:', data.Items);
                // Process the query results here
            }
        }
```

I am getting empty response, but when I try it with GS-Index results are getting fetched

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: Sorry I missed to add question in last. My Issue is I am getting empty response.